# JQuery sorting in table

Tags: jquery

I have a table, that looks like this:

```
<table class="sortabletable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 80px;" class="sort-numeric">Nummer</th>
      <th style="width: 160px;" class="sort-alphabetic">Navn</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="jLineContainer">
    <tr class="journal_line">
      <td><input type="hidden" name="lineno"/><input type="text" value="2088"/></td>
      <td ><input type="text" value="Anonymous"/></td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have then created a JQuery, that looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var getCellText = function ($cell) {
    $cell.find("input:not([name^=lineno])").each(function () {
      return this.value;
    });
  }

  $('table.sortabletable').each(function () {
    var $table = $(this);

    $('th', $table).each(function (column) {
      var findSortKey;

      ...

      if (findSortKey) {
        $(this).addClass('clickable').click(function () {

          var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();

          $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
            row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
          });

          rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) return -1;
            if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) return 1;
            return 0;
          });

          $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
            $table.children('tbody').append(row);
            row.sortKey = null;
          });

          $table.find('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This JQuery-function is found on http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part1

The problem is that I cannot set the function to start, when I click in the th

Comment: I think you accidentally the question.

Comment: Not trying to be a wise ass but you should first look for a library that already does what you want before writing it yourself. See my answer below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using Datatables: http://datatables.net/

This does exactly what you want and more.